# Time spent on a transformation exceeded 300 when solving the optimization problem

Tags: simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization

I have the code which shows below to solve an optimization problem, but it will show that it's over the time constraint of 300 seconds. Is there anyone who could help me solve it. Thanks.

```
m = 7;
n = 20;
coh = 5;
phi = 0.01/180*Pi;
r0 = 2;
segamax = 10;
segamay = 15;
seta[j_] := 2*Pi*(j - 1)/(2 n + 1);
c[k_] := c[k] /; RandomInteger[100] < 10;
ce[j_] := Sum[c[k]*E^(-I*k*seta[j]), {k, m}];
dd[j_] := Sqrt[r^2*(E^(I*seta[j]) + ce[j])*(E^(-I*seta[j]) +Conjugate[ce[j]])]/r0;
ee[j_] := (E^(I*seta[j]) + ce[j])/Conjugate[E^(I*seta[j]) + ce[j]];
bb[j_] := coh*Cot[phi]/(1 - Sin[phi])*dd[j]^(2 Sin[phi]/(1 - Sin[phi]));
cc[j_] := coh*Cos[phi]/(1 - Sin[phi])*dd[j]^(2 Sin[phi]/(1 -Sin[phi]))*ee[j];
eee[j_, t_] := E^(-I*t*seta[j]);
ma = Table[eee[j, t], {j, 1, (2*n + 1)}, {t, n, 1, -1}];
mb = Table[Conjugate[eee[j, t]], {j, 1, (2*n + 1)}, {t, 1, n}];
iii = Transpose[{Table[1, {2*n + 1}]}];
haib = Table[Join[ma[[i]], iii[[i]], mb[[i]]], {i, (2*n + 1)}];
ihaib = Inverse[N[haib]];
fb = Table[{bb[j]}, {j, 2 n + 1}];
fc = Table[{cc[j]}, {j, 2 n + 1}];
d1 = ihaib.fb;
e1 = ihaib.fc;
es = e1[[m - 1 ;; n, 1 ;; 1]];
d11 = d1[[1 ;; n + 1, 1 ;; 1]];
e11 = e1[[1 ;; n + 1, 1 ;; 1]];
f[s_] := Which[s < m - 1, Sum[(m - s - k)*c[m - s - k]*f[m - k + 1], {k, m - s - 1}] + c[s], True, c[s]];
e2[k_] := Which[k == 0, -2*Sum[j*f[j + 1]*d[j],
  {j, m - 1}] + (segamay - segamax)/2, k > m - 2, 0, True, -2*Sum[j*f[j + k + 1]*d[j], {j, m - k - 1}]];
e22 = Table[e2[k], {k, n, 0, -1}];
d[j_] := d1[[-j + n + 1, 1]];
e[j_] := e1[[-j + n + 1, 1]];
dx = 2 (segamax + segamay)/2 + coh*Cos[phi];
capf = Sum[Abs[es[[i, 1; 1]]], {i, n - m + 2}];
cons = {d[0] - dx == 0, e[0] - e2[0] == 0, Table[e11[[i]] == e22[[i]], {i, n + 1}]};
vars = {r, c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7]};
sol = NMinimize[{capf, cons}, {r, c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7]}]
```

Comment: `{LeafCount[capf],LeafCount[cons]}` gives `{242431,586827}` constants and operators and symbols in those expressions. Not surprising it can't do that in 300 seconds. Can you see if you can `Simplify` parts or all of those before you give those to `NMinimize`? And get those down to a small fraction of those numbers? That might help you.

Comment: @Bill This is invalid syntax and a misuse of `Assuming`. `Assuming` can't be used to set options. It just sets `$Assumptions`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I apologize for my mistake. I had found another StackExchange answer which I though showed how to pass `TimeConstraint` information to `Simplify` used inside `NMinimize` but I have searched and haven't found that answer again. I must have misunderstood. Sorry.

Comment: @Bill Maybe one could temporarily change the default option value using `SetOptions[Simplify, TimeConstraint -> bigNumber]` and also for `FullSimplify`.  I have not checked whether this works or not.

Comment: Bill and Szabolcs, thank you so much for your help. I tried to decrease the value of 'm' & 'n' and also increase the TimeConstraint to Infinity. But it still cannot show results. @Bill May I ask how do you know the expression might need 250 pages to print? Thanks.

Comment: As shown above, I calculated `LeafCount[capf]` and it returned 242431. That is the number of symbols and operators and constants needed to write out `capf` in Mathematica. Each of those symbols will take at least several characters to print and there are additional things like `[]` that I don't believe are in that count. So a quick estimate was it would take perhaps 250 pages to print that. Try modifying your code to just display `capf` on the screen and try to estimate how many lines that is. Then repeat with `cons`

Comment: @Bill Thank you so very much. I will try it.